Delete new sheets script
I created a Google Sheet that functions as a timetable for a non-profit organisation I volunteer at.
Each sheet serves as a weekly timetable. Anyone with access to the link can edit the document so volunteers with the link can write choose a sheet (a week) and write their name in the available slots for that week.
I noticed that new sheets randomly appear in my document. I believe this is due to the fact that some volunteers access the document on their phone and they must somehow unvoluntarily create new sheets.
I looked into a way to only allow users to edit specific cells in the available sheets but that seems too complicated for my understanding of the Apps Scripts. I searched online and found a simpler solution with the following script which should automatize deleting new sheets if not created by the owner (me).
Here is the script :
// Deletes any tab named "Feuille N" where N is a number 
function DeleteNewSheets() {
var newSheetName = /^Feuille[\d]+$/
var ssdoc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = ssdoc.getSheets();
// is the change made by the owner ?
if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() == ssdoc.getOwner().getEmail()) {
return;
}
// if not the owner, delete all unauthorised sheets
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (newSheetName.test(sheets[i].getName())) {
  ssdoc.deleteSheet(sheets[i])
}
}
}

I set a trigger as :









Choose which function to run
DeleteNewSheets


Which runs at deployment
Head


Select event source
From Spreadsheet


Select event type
On change


Failure notification settings
Weekly



I accessed the spreadsheet in incognito mode to see if it would work but newly created sheets are not deleted. In addition, I tried to manually run the script with new empty sheets in the document to see if they would be deleted but again nothing seems to happen.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't images of code, instead add the code as text. The same for trigger settings, instead of adding a screenshot of the trigger settings dialog, add the settings using text. This might found as shocking for users comming here expecting some sort of help service. This site is not that. To learn the ropes of this site please study carefully [tour].

Hello Wicket. Thank you for your feedback. I tried to paste the code using the indicated shortcut in the prompt (ctrl+k) but the prompt did not disappear after following its instructions and I was left unable to post my message. Would you kindly give me further instructions on how to past code in a proper way? Also, I believed my original question, ie before the end is edited out, belonged to the "Get answers to practical, detailed questions" as consulted in the Tour you hyerplinked me. Would you please let me know how I can make sure it does ? Thank you.

To paste content use Ctrl-V. Ctrl-K add markdown to format content as code. For further details on using the Stack Overflow editor, click the Help (?) button on the Editor toolbar. You might have to follow the link Learn More... or search [meta].

Another option is that you contact Stack Overflow support. Go to this page footer, look for the Company section, then click on Contact Us.

I was able to copy part of the code into the "Enter code here" section and manually add each line below the first one manually. Thank you for your support.

Google Apps Script might be complex when using to automate non-simple tasks specially when working on shared spreadsheet with multiple editors.
I suggest you to include in your personal development plan, whatever you call it, to include learning the basics of JavaScript as this is the programming language used by Google Apps Scripts.
If you haven't done yet, read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting.
To test by yourself a script that works on a spreadsheet shared with multiple editors, you will need to use at least two accounts, one to play the role of the spreadsheet owner, and the other an editor.
Regarding using a Change trigger, you should plan your tests carefully. With the information included giving a specific suggestion will be based on guesses and this might lead to having a lot of back and forth which the Question and Answer structure of this site is specifically designed to avoid.
Tips:

You might want to make copy of the spreadsheet, so you can isolate your tests from the noise that other users might introduce.

While running tests, set the trigger failure notification settings from weecly to immdiately.

You migth find helpful to spend time learnin programming concepts like



Pure function
Side effects
Testing

Unit testing
Integration testing



